# Redirect to profile path of user with username as to_param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

To show User's in my rails app I use their username in a `to_param` method. 
In the controller, I was using:

```
User.find_by_username(params[:id])
```

with routes looking like:

```
match '/:id', to: "users#show"....
```

Since today, I switched it to

```
Controller
  User.find_by(username: params[:username])
Routes.rb
  match '/:username', to: 'users#show',
```

My routes work and it's gets to the user, but when I try to update the user's settings, it redirects to the root_url and doesn't change the settings...

User's controller Update Action

```
def update 
  @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
  params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Your account has been updated."
    redirect_to edit_profile_path(@user)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

This was working fine until I changed it today to the `find_by(username: params[:username])`

where did I go wrong?

**UPDATE**

Routes.rb

```
resources :users
match '/:username', to: 'users#show', as: 'profile', via: 'get'
match '/:username/account', to: 'users#edit', via: 'get', as: 'edit_profile'
```

I'm assuming I need to changes the resources :users to use the username param instead of :id????

Comment: post your routes file please, and post the output of '$> rake routes | grep user'

Comment: I just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update action is expecting an :id parameter. You can check this by executing `$> rake routes | grep user`.

Add this to your routes:

```
put '/users/:username', to: 'users#update', as: :user
```

Comment: Thanks that works! I also had to add a `patch` as well in addition to the `put`